# Documents for US Citizen traveling to Ukraine?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, paperwork, ukraine

Do I need to show anything other than my passport when traveling to Ukraine? I am from the United States and was wondering if they require any documents? I will be staying for 18 days with someone who lives in Ukraine.

Answer (score 5):

Let's [ask Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=UA&selDest=Mexico&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point(s)%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C):

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for the period of intended stay.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of USA for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers with an emergency or a
>     temporary passport.
>
> A max. stay of 90 days is granted within any 180 days period
>     to nationals of USA.
>
> Warning: Visitors not holding return/onward ticket could be refused entry.

The US Department of State has [further information for visitors](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/ukraine.html) to Ukraine. Note that it says proof of health insurance and sufficient funds are required.

There's important information and warnings in there should your travel plans involve Crimea or Eastern Ukraine.

Have a nice trip.

Comment: Proof of funds and insurance may still be asked for but usually aren't as of late.